# Code-Editor Plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, code-editor

I'm looking to find some kind of plugin similar to this plugin stackoverflow uses to ask questions. Allowing the person who is asking the quesiton to customize his/her question with code, images, bold letters, etc..I like how it knows that your typing code when you tab once or twice for example. I would be using it for an mvc4 project to let users type tutorials with  a little code in there description. I tried looking at code mirror but it seems way to complicated to use. Are there any simple ways or plugins I can implement something like this into a textarea or some kind of input? Thanks for any adice

Comment: it is a customized one , you can use tinymce www.tinymce.com

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few libraries that you can take a look at:

- http://steamdev.com/snippet/
- http://www.tinymce.com/
- http://codemirror.net/

Personally I use the first one. They are all easy to implement though, what problem did you experience using codemirror?

Comment: Are you able to show an example of how you can use the first on please? I am a n00b ASP.NET user and I am struggling. All I want it to display some output from a log file to a user on a razor page.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the editor that is used on StackOverflow is [open source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/) so you can incorporate it into the site you are working on.  The editor uses markdown syntax instead of full on HTML (such as TinyMCE) so it's a little more limited in what kind of formatting it supports.  Whether it serves your needs or not will depend on how rich an editing experience you need to provide and how complex the resulting output needs to be.